# Cakephp get associative sum group by in postgres

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have two tables

```
coins       summary_coins 
--------    -------------
id | name    id| date                |  get_count | coin_id
===|====    ==============================================
 1 |lira     1 | 2020-02-16 16:55:50 |  20        | 1
 2 |A        1 | 2020-03-16 16:55:50 |  12        | 1
 3 |B        1 | 2020-03-16 16:55:50 |  20        | 1
```

My Expected result

```
name get_count   previous_month_count  
Lira 32          20
```

I have tried below cakephp method to get expected result

```
    public function getCount($start_date,$end_date,$previous_month_start_date,$previous_month_end_date)
    {
        $query = $this->find();
        $query
            ->select([
                        'Coins.id',
                        'Coins.name',
                        'curr_get_count' => $query->func()->sum('SummaryCoins.get_count'),
                        'prev_get_count' => $query->func()->sum('SummaryCoins.get_count'),
 
            ])
            ->matching('SummaryCoins')
            ->where([
                'SummaryCoins.user_id' => 1,
                'SummaryCoins.date >' => '2021-04-01',
                'SummaryCoins.date <' => '2021-05-31'
            ])
            ->group([
                'Coins.id',
             ]);
        return $query;
   }
```

Here I am getting present month range, how I will get previous month count ?

Comment: Do you know how to do it in plain SQL? eg is your problem that you don't know how to translate that to the query builder?

Comment: @ndm I actually don't know how to do it in plan sql. Would you please give some hints ? If I have query I think I am able to transfer it in query builder.

Comment: @NiloyRony when I am struggling with the ORM, I generally figure out how to do it in plain SQL and then figure out how to convert that into the ORM. There are edge-cases where I feel its not worth transfering into the ORM, generally highly complex reports and for those I execute the SQL directly (still using PDO for binded parameters of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to achieve this, subqueries, multiple custom joins, case expressions, etc...

I would suggest that you try case expressions first, where depending on your date conditions you either return `SummaryCoins.get_count`, `NULL` (which is being ignored by `SUM`) or `0` (in case you want the sum to be `0` instead of `NULL` if no rows are matching your conditions), eg generate SQL like:

```sql
SUM(
    CASE WHEN
        SummaryCoins.date >= '2020-03-01' AND
        SummaryCoins.date <= '2020-03-31'
    THEN
        SummaryCoins.get_count
    ELSE
        0
    END
)
```

```php
$query
    ->select([
        'Coins.id',
        'Coins.name',
        'curr_get_count' => $query->func()->sum(
            $query
                ->newExpr()
                ->addCase(
                    [
                        $query->newExpr()->add([
                            'SummaryCoins.date >=' => $start_date,
                            'SummaryCoins.date <=' => $end_date,
                        ])
                    ],
                    [$query->identifier('SummaryCoins.get_count'), 0]
                    [null, 'integer']
                )
        ),
        'prev_get_count' => $query->func()->sum(
            $query
                ->newExpr()
                ->addCase(
                    [
                        $query->newExpr()->add([
                            'SummaryCoins.date >=' => $previous_month_start_date,
                            'SummaryCoins.date <=' => $previous_month_end_date,
                        ]),
                    ],
                    [$query->identifier('SummaryCoins.get_count'), 0]
                    [null, 'integer']
                )
        ),
    ])
```

Also note that you should use `>=` and `<=` to make the conditions inclusive, otherwise the first day and the last day of the month would be ignored in case the time part is `00:00:00`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & SQL > Query Builder > Case Statements](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements)**